# Xamarin.Forms: identify and remove unused NuGets?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.

I've been cursed with the Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: `Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbp` thing.

I can only find resolutions of it for Android's native IDE, not Visual Studio.

In trying to fix it I've been (probably unwisely) adding NuGet packages left and right to try to get find the class that Java.Lang can't identify.

Now I have a bunch of packages that probably aren't doing anything, but it's hard to tell which is which, and I'm wondering if there's some easy way to identify which NuGet packages aren't actually in use.

Comment: It may have but I haven't tried it. I'm torn because I don't want to award the answer to the guy who gave less information than you did, but I don't want to give you the answer while I haven't tried out your solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

No way you can do this. It is not a spammy answer but a really good one.

Comment: A negative result is just as valuable as a positive one. Thanks Path.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have a bunch of packages that probably aren't doing anything,
>   but it's hard to tell which is which, and I'm wondering if there's
>   some easy way to identify which NuGet packages aren't actually in use.

**In fact**, VS does not have the ability to detect unused nugets in the project itself but **ReSharper** extension can realize your requirement.

**Suggestion**

1) use [ReSharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8pz2nb-g6AIVSaqWCh2BHAGqEAAYASAAEgJ4l_D_BwE) and it has a function called [Removing unused references](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Optimizing_References.html).

> The easiest way to clean up project references is to click Remove All
>   Unused References ThemedIcon RemoveAllUnusedReferences Screen Gray  on
>   the toolbar. If you want ro retain some unused references or remove
>   some of the used references (and manually resolve the compilation
>   errors that follow), you can make the corresponding selection and
>   click Remove Selected References.

Hope it could help you.